# set random background color

Tags: html, css

cant believe im asking this question but,

why this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf=8">
        <style type="text/css">
            #posts {
                width: 90%;
                height: 700px;
                margin: auto
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="return ran_col()">
        <div id="posts">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ran_col() { //function name
                var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
                var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0']; //Set your colors here
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
                document.getElementById('posts').style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this doesn't?
its pretty much the same code,
if anyone can edit the code that would be brilliant?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Splash!</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6.5;url=home.html" />



<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylessplash.css" type="text/css">



</head>


<body id="posts">

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function ran_col() { //function name
                var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
                var letters = ['000000','FF0000'; //Set your colors here
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
                document.getElementById('posts').style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
            }
</script>

<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <p>
        <span>u</span>
        <span>u</span>
        <span>H</span>
        <span>!</span>
    </p>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

need to add more text but no more is needed.
need to add more text but no more is needed.
need to add more text but no more is needed.
need to add more text but no more is needed.
need to add more text but no more is needed.
need to add more text but no more is needed.

Comment: on second example your script is not invoked ?

Comment: you aren't running the function in the second code

Comment: Looks like you don't call ran_col() in the 2nd example. In the first example you call it onload().

Comment: var letters doesn't have a closing `]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use that code to set the background to a specific element (not to the whole body like you did). To set the background of the whole page, instead of

```js
document.getElementById('posts').style.background = color;
```

you will need

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

On your second code block you are simply creating a function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function ran_col() { //function name
                var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
                var letters = ['000000','FF0000'; //Set your colors here
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
                document.getElementById('posts').style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
            }
</script>
```

It doesn't run because you are not invoking the function in form load or whenever you want. Which is shown in your 1st code block

```
<body onload="return ran_col()">
```